# React Navigation unwanted Bottom Border Radius in Modal

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I use a Bottom Tab Navigator with several different stacks in my React Native app. I have created a screen that opens like a modal using this in the screen options:

```
{ presentation: "modal" }
```

On iOS, phones with no physical home button (e.g. iPhone 12) get a strange **unwanted** bottom radius when the screen has been navigated to:

[image]

When the screen is being dismissed, the border radius gets even larger for a couple of seconds until it disappears completely:

[image]

I've tried changing the border radius on the screen's view but no luck. How do I get rid of this unwanted border radius? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at this reported issue: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/9933 Hope it helps.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm having the same issue